# Changing 'innerHTML' on <img> not changing image

Tags: javascript, html, image

Here is my code:

### HTML

```
<form>
  <img id='image' src=""/>
  <input type='text' id='text'>
  <input type="button" value="change picture" onclick="changeimage()">
</form>
```

### JavaScript

```
function changeimage() {
  var a=document.getElementById('text').value
  var c=a+".gif"
  c="\""+c+"\""
  var b= "<img src="+c+"\/>"

  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML=b
}
```

I have some GIF images. I want to write an image name in the textbox and then have the image become shown when the button is clicked. However, it's not happening. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should do this:

```
document.getElementById('image').src = c;
```

By doing `document.getElementById('image').innerHTML=b` you are trying to defined the HTML inside the `<img>` tag which is not possible.

Full script:

```
function changeimage() {
    var a = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var c = a + ".gif";

    document.getElementById('image').src = c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeimage() {
   var a = document.getElementById('text').value;
   document.getElementById('image').src = a + '.gif';
}
</script>
<form>
<img id='image' src=""/>
<input type='text' id='text'>
<input type="button" value="change picture" onclick="changeimage()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src","another.gif")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the `<img>` tag you need to update it's source, not it's inner HTML.

```
function changeimage()
{
  var a=document.getElementById('text').value
  var c=a+".gif"
  c="\""+c+"\""
  var elem = document.getElementById('image');
  elem.setAttribute('src', c);
}
```

Comment: what is the actual use of innerHTML??

Comment: @sovon it's used to change / access the HTML inside an element.